# How to rename all files in the same folder with different/random extentions in a directory on linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Lets say I have 28k files in a folder with different random file name extensions....
See example:

```
br.AQ5702419254531904.GD14700006
br.CT7465737800862080.MV94400009
etc
etc
br.RH5816804080109504.BE59800003
etc
ect
etc
```

28k later...

How would i change them all to

```
br.AQ5702419254531904.GD14700006.txt or *.json
br.CT7465737800862080.MV94400009.txt or *.json
br.RH5816804080109504.BE59800003.txt or *.json
```

Comment: `for i in *;do mv -vf $i $i.txt;done` <- this adds a .txt extension to all files in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a script like this:

```
while read -r path; do
  mv -v "${path}" "${path}.txt"
done < <(find . -type f -not '(' -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.json' ')' )
```

This invoke find (and also work on file in directories), ignoring txt/sjon, and renaming file with *.txt.

You may also do that directly on the command line:

```
find . -type f -not '(' -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.json' ')' | while read -r path; do mv -v "${path}" "${path}.txt"; done
```

However, still will create a subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

**You can also use the `rename` command (which can accept regex):**

```
rename 's/(br[.][A-Z0-9]{18}[.][A-Z0-9]{10})/\1.txt/g' *
```

If you wanted your regex to be broken down into multiple sets to make it more dynamic, you could do something like this:

```
rename 's/(br[.])([A-Z0-9]{18}[.])([A-Z0-9]{10})/\1\2\3.txt/g' *
```

This is a contrived example, but if you needed to do something like make  `br.AQ5702419254531904.GD14700006` into **`br.GD14700006.AQ5702419254531904.txt`**, you can do:

```
rename 's/(br[.])([A-Z0-9]{18}[.])([A-Z0-9]{10})/\1\3\2.txt/g' *
```

You'll notice that I flipped the remembered patterns, so that it was `\1\3\2` to make that change. Everything contained in it's own set of parenthesis constitutes a group for the remembered pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put 'em in a loop, you can use 'for':

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="<your_directory_path>"
cd $DIR

for FILE in `ls $DIR`
do

mv $FILE $FILE.txt

done
```